# ListView Different images per selection in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So what I want to do is have a different image for each list item in my App. I've been attempting to do this for a little while now and have no idea what I'm doing.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

[image]

How do I go about this? Here's my current code:

```java
package net.androidbootcamp.gamesandcoffee;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[ ] attraction = {"Games", "Coffee Shops"};
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.games, attraction));

    }
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, games.class));
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, coffee.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and my XML:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/games"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@+id/games"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/games"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have to create a Custom adapter for your Listview. You can google it for further details An example is here, http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

Comment: @Sunny I'll take a look here, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to create a custom adapter, where you can customize all the `ListView` items.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int imageViewResourceId) {
        super(context, imageViewResourceId);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
        }

        Item p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView ) v.findViewById(R.id.id);

            if (iv != null) {
                iv .setImageResource(R.id.xyz);
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: This uh. Seems pretty complicated. Is it the only way to go about this? I'm still rather new to this so I'm not quite understanding everything going on here

Comment: Please refer this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: Thank you, I will look at this.

Comment: Yes, this looks complicated, but oddly enough it is probably the leanest way to do it. I have done this quite some times and still don't understand why android makes it so complicated

Answer (score 0):

load the image resource id's to the array and pass to the list adapter in this way

```
int[] images = {R.drawables.firstimg,R.drawables.secondimg};
setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,images, attraction));
```

Crate CustomAdapter Class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;
int[] images;
String[] textdata;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int[] images,String[] textdata) {
    this.context = context;
    this.images=images;
    this.textdata=textdata;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return textdata.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = null;
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_listitem,parent,false);
    }else {
        row = convertView;
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.draweritemtext);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.draweritemimage);

    name.setText(textdata[position]);

    image.setImageResource(images[position]);
    return row;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return textdata.size();
}
```

}

Comment: I get the error 'Cannot resolve constructor' ([screenshot](http://puu.sh/lFeOJ.png))

Comment: create custom adapter to load data to the list

Comment: how exactly do I do that? I'm looking at numerous resources and am lost. Do I make a new activity? I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Following these two video tutorials, ***geared towards beginners***, I was able to arrive to my desired result. Thank you those who contributed, but none of the answers or resources provided were geared towards beginners that lack experience.

These are the videos I watched

[Android Studio Tutorial - 18 - ListView with Custom Adapter part-1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyk_ht8z6IA)

[Android Studio Tutorial - 19 - ListView with Custom Adapter part-2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzpwvZ4S27g)